# Why would New Repository Connection window not load?

Tags: windows-10, repository, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I've freshly installed [windows-10](/questions/tagged/windows-10) Pro N(64-bit)(not activated & fully updated to date) and downloaded [pentaho](/questions/tagged/pentaho) from [this](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files/latest/download) source. After installing [java](/questions/tagged/java) (64-bit) and creating an environment variable `PENTAHO_JAVA_HOME` with the path to its JRE folder I managed to start up `spoon.bat` properly.

However, I am unable to access repository menu:

[image: NOTHING IS LOADED]

Also when added : `-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla` as parameter to have:

```
if "%PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS%"=="" set PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms512m" "-Xmx7680m" "-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla"
```

And when clicked connect button with that the error below was raised in a window:

```
An unexpected error occurred in Spoon:  
No more handles [Could not detect registered XULRunner to use]
org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [Could not detect registered XULRunner to use]
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.create(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.core.dialog.ThinDialog.createDialog(ThinDialog.java:69)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryDialog.openCreation(RepositoryDialog.java:264)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.repo.RepositoryConnectMenu$2.widgetSelected(RepositoryConnectMenu.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.readAndDispatch(Spoon.java:1366)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.waitForDispose(Spoon.java:7984)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.start(Spoon.java:9245)
    at org.pentaho.di.ui.spoon.Spoon.main(Spoon.java:692)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.pentaho.commons.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:92)
```

Why is this happening and how to resolve it?

Comment: By contrast in Lubuntu 17.10 inside a VM with java + libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 is working seemingly without an issue.

Comment: I had the same problem with Pentaho 8.0. Reverted to Pentaho 7.1. Pentaho 7.0 has repository setup issues too. I guess the guy there are changing the UI. It would be nice to tell them your adventure https://community.hds.com/community/products-and-solutions/pentaho/

Comment: The issue is resolved now. But I don't know how. I downloaded firefox, I've overwritten swt files under libswt folder from the files from [here](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.6.1-201009090800/#SWT) with consideration to 32 and 64-bit architectures. Also switched `PENTAH_JAVA_HOME` to `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_161` but this resulted in a startup crash on the spoon. Then I removed Pentaho files including the ones in `C:\Users\username\` and re-unpacked and voilà! It works. I then reversed the env. var. back to `C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_162` and it still works